# Authentication Failure on the first Ubuntu boot from my USB?

Tags: boot, usb

I have a old HP compaq computer. My windows XP on that computer has corrupted, so I decided to install Ubuntu on it. I used the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfEbsf06IwU

I download the 32bit Ubuntu iso file since that computer is 32 bit. Once I boot it from the usb device with or without installing it, the ubuntu logo with the five dots come up. It searches for my network configurations, and does not find it. Then it says that "booting with a network configuration.

Then this screen comes up:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJcaH.jpg)

Please help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: what program did you use to create the USB Ubuntu drive?

Comment: I used http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: Download the ISO manually and then do a checmsum on it to make sure it was downloaded correctly.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by downloading it manually and checmsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to ubuntu.com and download ubuntu.  Then you need to verify what you downloaded has downloaded properly.  You do that by doing something called a checksum.

You can download it here - http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso

Then do a md5sum.
If you are on Ubuntu you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install md5sum
```

Then you can check the iso like

```
md5sum ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso
```

If you are on windows you can download a program to do it
http://www.etree.org/cgi-bin/counter.cgi/software/md5sum.exe

It should be

```
0bc058cdc75fb75d4922c7c74c4cd6b1
```

Let me know what happens after you verify this.

Comment: I did this, but the md5sum is not opening. I saw that the link I download my iso was different. I am going to try with your iso file now.

Comment: which md5sum isn't working?  The one for Windows?

Comment: dude, thanks so much! Your link for the iso file is working!

Comment: glad it worked for you.  please mark it as your answer. :D

Comment: i marked this as my answer, appreciate the help :)